# Python script struck while creating dictionary as for each key of dictionary , there are multiple values( 300 entries) list

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

I am a beginner. I have written a script which take input list of 10 million entries (in the form of a:b where a and b are alphanumeric).

Now I want to create a dictionary from these entries.  For lot of list entries, the second part (after the colon) is common. (for example a:b, f:b, k:b -- in that case my key would be b and values will be a list [a,f,k]).

But somehow my script is struck. I can see from the logs that the script is struck and log size is not increasing. (For every key of my dictionary, there is a list of size between 400 to 500. Can that be a issue?)

My script is working fine if my input list contains fewer entries.

List name is match

```
print 'match2 list: %s' % match2 # it shows the 10 million entries in form of a:b as expected 
for i in xrange(len(match2)):
    print 'Before Splitted variable : %s' % match2[i] # this print is for information
    templist = re.split(':', '%s' % match2[i])
    print 'Splitted list : %s' % templist # this print is for information
    length3 = len(templist)
    print "Length3 :%d" %length3
    key1 = templist[1]
    value1 = templist[0]
    if example.has_key(key1):
       example[key1].append(value1)
    else:
       example[key1] = value1
```

Please give your suggestions.

Comment: This code looks fine . . . a bit ugly and inefficient, but fine ;)  I'd add something to print out i, and check if it's always failing at the same point - could be an issue with your input data or some of the surrounding logic.

Comment: It doesn't relate to the question you're asking, but I think `re.split` is overkill here.  You could just do `templist = match2[i].split(':', maxsplit=1)`, which will have the added benefit of guaranteeing that `len(templist) == 2`, since made at most one split.

Comment: You could even go a step further if you know that your list entries always have a `:` in them and do `value1, key1 = match2[i].split(':', maxsplit=1)`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem is here:

```
if example.has_key(key1):
   example[key1].append(value1)
else:
   example[key1] = value1
```

When `example` does not contain `key1`, it creates a new entry for it, whose value is the string `value1`. If example *does* contain `key1`, it attempts to append the string `value1` to whatever is already there. However, this does not make sense. You can't use `append` to append two strings.

You probably want:

```
if example.has_key(key1):
   example[key1].append(value1)
else:
   example[key1] = [value1] #the value is a list containing one string
```

Comment: Nice catch, though shouldn't this throw an AttributeError and bail  out?

Comment: Yes, that's what happened when I tested the code. I suspect OP has a try-catch somewhere higher up that's eating the error silently.

Comment: If it had a `try: except:` earlier, wouldn't it either drop out of the loop immediately or continue the loop, rather than freeze?